# build server comprehends modules in multi module build

Tags: jenkins, build, teamcity, bamboo

Is there a build server that understands and can report on build results per module in a maven multi module build?

We use bamboo and unless I create individual jobs for each module it treats the build like one big thing.  I want users to be able to subscribe to modules individually for notification etc.

I also want the build system to run the build in parallel across hosts (-T5 not in threads but on different machines)

Can Jenkins, cloud bees, team city, quick build do either of those or do they all require hand editing build configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of since the build is just 1 maven execution that contains multiple modules.

What you could do in Bamboo is in your Compilation Stage is have a Job for each Maven Module that would allow you to have the build run across multiple agents concurrently.  However you would need to ensure modules didn't depend on each other for code since they could face compilation errors when each one runs and you wouldn't get unique notifications based off each section.

This leaves you creating a separate build for each module that would give you control over that modules notifications.

Comment: Thanks but replicating 300 jobs seems the wrong approach.  We tried splitting into a few jobs with profiles.  That's ok but not nearly as dynamic as I'd like.  I believe I can do much the same with jenkins workflow plugin and profiles. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workflow+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

Did you already play around with build concurrency? https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Configuring+concurrent+builds